# Finite difference method, boundaries

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-difference-methods

I have a problem solving this problem. 
$$
−3u''(x) + (x + 2)u(x) = 4x, \hspace{10pt} x \in (−1, 1), 
$$
*subject to*
$$
u'(−1) + 4u(−1) = 3, \hspace{10pt} −u'(1) + 2u(1) = 0,\hspace{10pt} h=0.001
$$
*Then* $p = -3,\, q= (x+2)$.

---

*So I got to the point that I can estimate* 
$$
\frac{p}{h^2}u(x-h) + \left(\frac{2p}{h^2} + q\right)u(x) + \frac{p}{h^2}u(x+h) = f(x).
$$

---

For equation above I need at least boundaries and
I know that I can rewrite $u'(x)$ like this: 
$$
u'(x) \approx \frac{u(x+h) − u(x)}{h}
$$
and rewrite boundaries as: 
$$
\frac{u(-0.999) - u(-1)}{0.001} + 4u(-1) =3
$$
$$
-\frac{u(1.001) - u(1)}{0.001} + 2u(1) = 0
$$

---

But this is where I got stucked and I cannot find boundaries. Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Comment: I guess your u(x-1) and u(x+1) should be u(x-h) and u(x+h)? What is f(x) though and when you say "it still didn't help"  can you say what you mean. Try to be clear about what your problem is rather than just noting down a few thoughts.

Comment: I eddited the question. I got stuck at evaluating the boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the ghost-point method. Intuitively, ghost-point method is based on the analytic continuity of the solution. It assumes that the governing equation not only holds for all $x\in\left(-1,1\right)$, but also holds on $x=-1$ and $x=1$. With this trick, the Robin (or simply Neumann) boundary conditions could be implemented in a natural fashion.

Suppose
$$
-1=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_N=1
$$
are your equi-spaced grid points, with
$$
x_j=jh-1,\quad h=\frac{2}{N}.
$$
Now define
\begin{align}
x_{-1}&=-1-h,\\
x_{N+1}&=1+h.
\end{align}
Plus, implement
$$
-3\frac{u_{j+1}-2u_j-u_{j-1}}{h^2}+\left(x_j+2\right)u_j=4x_j,\quad j=0,1,\cdots,N
$$
for the governing equation, with boundary conditions
\begin{align}
\frac{u_1-u_{-1}}{2h}+4u_0&=3,\\
-\frac{u_{N+1}-u_{N-1}}{2h}+2u_N&=0.
\end{align}

Note that for the governing equation, the index $j$ runs from $0$ to $N$, instead of the usual boundary-value-problem case from $1$ to $N-1$. Thus combine the main scheme with the boundary conditions from above, you will be able to determine all of $x_{-1}$, $x_0$, ..., $x_{N+1}$, because there are $N+3$ unknowns, and you have $N+3$ linear equations.

Comment: Thank you, I understand more or less. Just one think, can you please explain how did you get the governing equation?

Comment: @SimonHarvan: The governing equation is exactly the standard central finite difference scheme for your $$-3u''(x)+\left(x+2\right)u(x)=4x.$$That is, let $u_j\approx u(x_j)$, and thus$$u''(x_j)\approx\frac{u_{j+1}-2u_j+u_{j-1}}{h^2}.$$